# Doctrine2, retry insert with different value on duplicate key

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, flush, duplicates

I'm trying to create a certain hash. The following path is followed:

1. Create some hash object with a unique key on $hash
2. constructor fills in a seed to generate the actual $hash
3. try saving it
4. if saving failed because of error 23000 (duplicate key), make a different hash and repeat till a unique hash is made that doesn't exist yet.

Now here's my problem. Using Doctrine2, it closes the EntityManager when a query fails due to an SQL error. In my case that's no problem because I will retry it.

One solution is to search the database if the hash already exists. Due to the very, very low amount of a collision (md5) and the need to do stuff as fast as possible (every ms I can save is worth it), I want to skip the check.

Another solution that I thought was worth a shot, was to `clone` the entity manager. However, internally the entity manager was already passed to objects inside and they are not cloned but passed with the reference.

A third solution is to use the registry and create a new entity manager. However, outside of this object I will not have the right entity manager:

- Object A gets EM -> does query
- Object B gets EM -> does query > error > creates new EM
- Object C gets EM -> does query with new EM
- Object A > does query > error, already closed because already got it at step 1.

What should I do to be able to quickly insert? I need to do it via entities, I'm not going to make flat DQL/SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding a unique hash before persisting?

```
do {
    $unique_hash = md5(microtime()); // Work out your hash here.
    $existing = $repository->findOneByHash($unique_hash);
    if (!$existing) {
        break; // else carry on until we get one.
    }
} while (1);

// Use your unique hash here.
```

Comment: That's my current implementation. However as mentioned already, this is too slow. Say it takes 3 ms to execute this select. That would mean that over 200000 hash generations, my script would take 600000ms, which comes down to 10 minutes. This would mean that my batch would run for 25 minutes instead of 15 every hour.

Comment: Maybe get all hashes into a PHP array, then loop through that using in_array instead of one at a time over the database?

Reopening the entity manager each time there is a collision would be even slower.